# jQuery Mobile List View: Change a Value When Clicked

Tags: jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm having trouble phrasing my question. So I have a listview in jQuery mobile and it was created dynamically. Rather than link to an outside page when a list item is clicked, I just want to be able to grab the text of the item they clicked.

In my case its a list of names, and I want to know which one they clicked. I've created the list in HTML with:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="b">

        <div id="friends_list_view" class="content-primary" data-theme="c"> 
            <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme="c">
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

When an item is clicked, I want to run some function using the name they have selected. How can I do that?

and then dynamically updated it later with:

```
var listString = null;
for(i in session_library){
        listString =  '<li><a href="#">'+session_library[i]['name']+'</a></li>';
        $("#friends_list_view ul").append(listString);

}

$("#friends_list_view ul").listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that your listview will look like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-theme="c" id="my_listview">
         <li>Row A</li>
         <li>Row B</li>
</ul>
```

you can register a click event handler which will give you the `<li>` text back, e.g.

```
$('#my_listview').delegate('li', 'click', function () {
    alert(this.innerText);
} );    
​
```

**Edit**: Changed `vclick` to `click`. See the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html).

Comment: Be careful with `vclick`. In some OSes (Android < 3.0 mostly) it will fire two click events, and if the click event navigates or changes the content around the clicked area then the second click can actually fire on a different element. `click` has a delay before it fires but this is by design, so the device can decide if the user is tapping, tap-holding, or swiping.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. See the documentation on this: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html. I haven't seen the warning on `click` vs `vclick` there yet.